# ios tasks, coregraphics animations

Tags: c#, ios, .net, multithreading, xamarin

Recently I works with xamarin IDE and I've coded some basics lets say 'animations'. Is it a good way of coding to update UIView in another task like this? I wrote a class UIBackgroundView class, which generates CoreGraphics circles via given path and arc in overrided "Draw" method.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        backgroundView.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        backgroundView.arcs = new List<Arc>();
        for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        {
            x = rand.Next(0, (int)backgroundView.Bounds.Width);
            y = rand.Next(0, (int)backgroundView.Bounds.Height);
            backgroundView.arcs.Add(new Arc(x, y, 7 * n, 0, (nfloat)(2 * Math.PI), true,
                                            new CGColor(0,
                                                        (float)rand.Next(70, 100) / 100,
                                                        (float)rand.Next(70, 100) / 100, 0.2f), (float)rand.Next(50, 300) / 100));
        }
        backgroundView.SetNeedsDisplay();
        Task task = new Task(generateCircles);
        task.Start();
    }

    void generateCircles()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
            {
                if (backgroundView.arcs[n].y + backgroundView.arcs[n].radius > 0)
                    backgroundView.arcs[n].y -= backgroundView.arcs[n].speed;
                else
                {
                    backgroundView.arcs[n].y = backgroundView.Bounds.Height + backgroundView.arcs[n].radius;
                    backgroundView.arcs[n].color = new CGColor(0, (float)rand.Next(70, 100) / 100, (float)rand.Next(70, 100) / 100, 0.2f);
                }
            }
            InvokeOnMainThread(() => backgroundView.SetNeedsDisplay());
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

    }
```

Comment: If nothing else, you're going to need locks to share data (`backgroundView` and its contents) between threads.

Comment: Do you have any examples? I'am new with Threading.Tasks, I am used to callbacks and ThreadPoll.

Comment: Basically, threading is hard to do correctly.  There's a lot of stuff you need to know without which your program may seem to work, but will under the right circumstances cause it to go up in flames.  It's not the sort of thing you can do correctly by experimentation or stealing bits of code from here and there.  If you want to actually learn all that stuff, I recommend Joe Albahari's C# threading book (available as a free PDF).  If you're not ready to do a lot of learning, I'd recommend you just avoid using multiple threads.